# Is there a way to free all nodes in a linked list in one go instead of iterating through each node?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, free

I have the following linked list that has several nodes which have been attached to it. Is there away to free all the notes at once instead of iterating through each node?

This is the struct I have:

```
struct Courses{
        char *courseName;
        int creditValue;
        Courses *next;
    };Courses;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own, intermediate allocator that allocates a big block of (say) 1000 node structures.  They you can build your list by "allocating" nodes out of your big chunk one at a time, with a simple variable to keep track of how many you've used, and some code to catch the case that you've used them all up.

Then when it's time to free your list, you can just free that one block in one go.

In your example, you may also have to worry about memory dynamically allocated for the `courseName` pointer.  You can handle that, too, although your intermediate allocator gets more complicated, because it ends up being more of a general-purpose `malloc` replacement, not just a special-purpose `Courses` node allocator.

Comment: Of course, to account for the possibility of more nodes than will fit in one block, you need a data structure -- probably a linked list -- to track the blocks.  And of course, you need to traverse *that* list iteratively.  (Or pull it all up one more level.  Or two ....)

Comment: @John Bollinger To be fair, OP asked "Is there a way to free ...  in one go ...?" and this answer does provide _an_ answer, including its short-comings.  Should OP use this approach?  Likely not, yet depends on many things not stated by OP.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sure, but I swept that under the rug (for now) by saying "some code to catch the case that you've used them all up".  The OP looks like he's writing a toy program; I'm betting 1,000 nodes will be plenty.  If not, he can probably figure it out himself, or ask for clarification.  Myself, I have used exactly this technique, with a linked list of blocks to free, several times.  (In my own case I've never imposed the requirement that the linked list of blocks to free use the same code, or have the same "free in one go" requirement, as the top-level data structure.)

Comment: Sure, I'm not saying you're wrong.  I'm just pointing out that this is a special case solution, not a general one, even if the special case can be made quite large.  The only truly general solutions to the problem (in C) involve terminating the program ...  as, indeed, I am *certain* I answered to a near-identical question within the last few days.

Answer (score 3):

No. There's no way other than iterating over the list.

On modern operating systems, allocated memory will be reclaimed by the operating system once the process exits. So you can avoid free()'ing yourself. But this is not a good alternative especially if the program is a long running one or nor is it a universal approach to free memory.

Comment: But will this cause Valgrind to still pop up warnings?

Comment: Yes. Valgrind will complain about memory leaks.